# How to prevent parent div styles in child elements

Tags: php, html, css

CSS style:

```
.disable{
  pointer-events:none;
  opacity:0.5;
}
```

Html code:

```
  <div class="col-md-12 <?php echo $class;?>"> 
      <div class="image-title">
          <?php echo $icon?>
      </div>
  </div>
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
    if($p['status'] == 'inactive'){
      $class = 'disable';
      $icon = '<span class="icon icon-bag" onclick="" id="" style="font-size:24px;"></span>';
    }
    else{
      $class= '';
      $icon = '<span class="icon icon-cancel-3" onclick="inactive('.$checkbox[0]["UniqueID"].',this)" id="'.$checkbox[0]["UniqueID"].'" style="font-size:24px;"></span>';
    }
?>
```

Some time disable class will be on div, but I don't care. I just want to display span class same as it displaying without disable class and it can be clickable. How can I do it? Please help me and thanks in advance. I apologize if I made any grammatical or spelling mistakes.

Comment: `.disable span {pointer-events:auto;}` just take a look at the spec https://www.w3.org/TR/pointerevents/ (or tuts https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events - https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/pointer-events/ ) `opacity` will be inherited anyway, you may use rgba() colors instead or mix-blend-mode eventually

Comment: @GCyrillus it not working

Comment: a quick example from you structure: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yVyLez and pointer-events

Comment: You cannot prevent `opacity` from affecting child elements.

Comment: Remember, you have full control over the HTML you emit! Just put the span outside the div if the div has `disable`. Problem solved.